# Duplicate error when update column in the same table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am getting error code `Error Code: 1062 Duplicate Entry for KEY Primary`.

The Procedure is suppose to increment `workshift` by `1` day each week. Ex, `6001` is Monday shift, `6002` Tuesday and so on each time it's called.

I know i'm getting the error due to as soon as `6001` == `6002` in first `if` , then there is 2 `6002` with same PK. Is there anyway to fix this?

Here is current table.

`roster
 employee  branch  workShift
   0001      01       6001
   0001      01       6002
   0001      01       6003
   0001      01       6004`

Table **after** call to update roster:

`roster
 employee  branch  workShift
   0001      01       6002
   0001      01       6003
   0001      01       6004
   0001      01       6005`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `UpdateRoster`(in employeeid char(8), in BranchID int(11))
BEGIN
 DECLARE hours_max INT(35);
 DECLARE fin INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE empid CHAR(8);
 DECLARE brnid INT(11);
 DECLARE workshfid INT(11);
 DECLARE emp INT;

 DECLARE employee_roster CURSOR FOR
         SELECT EmployeeID, BranchID, WorkingShiftID
         FROM DutyRoster;
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin = 1;

 OPEN employee_roster;
 REPEAT
    FETCH employee_roster INTO empid, brnid, workshfid;
        IF workshfid = '6001' THEN
            SET workshfid = '6002';

        ELSEIF workshfid = '6002' THEN
            SET workshfid = '6003';

        ELSEIF workshfid = '6003' THEN
            SET workshfid = '6005';

        ELSEIF workshfid = '6005' THEN
            SET workshfid = '6007';

        ELSEIF workshfid = '6007' THEN
            SET workshfid = '6008';

        ELSE 
            SET workshfid = '6001';
        END IF;

    UPDATE DutyRoster
    SET WorkingShiftID = workshfid;

  UNTIL fin
  END REPEAT;
  CLOSE employee_roster;
END
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `WorkingShiftID` is the primary key of the DutyRoster table, and that you're trying to set this to the same value in all rows:

```
UPDATE DutyRoster SET WorkingShiftID = workshfid;
```

Presumably, the problem is you forgot to include a `WHERE` clause in that statement, so the update could be restricted to a single row.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I would add new column with autoincrement numerical value. And then update the minimum or maximum value from that new added column.

Answer (score -1):

In this case,remove the primary key constraint from the "workshift" field and in place of it add an auto increment field let suppose "workshiftId" and make it primary key to maintain the uniqueness of the record. Now you can do your workshift increment task without any error.